# Подключение к трансляции через python

Tags: python, видео

Я только начал осваивать python и многое еще остается непонятным. Прошу помочь с возникшей трудностью.
Суть в следующем:
Через запрос к стриму онлайн камеры

```
import requests
req = requests.get("https://599da0b457148.streamlock.net:1936/traffic/trafcam6zel.stream/playlist.m3u8")
req.status_code
```

Получаю ответ 403 (Forbidden)
Однако, после захода на сайт используя браузер, где этот стрим опубликован (https://kgd.ru/traffic/camera/18-zelenogradsk-plyazh)
подключение через скрипт начинает осуществляться нормально, ответ req.status_code получаю "200" и я нормально подключаюсь к стриму используя cv2.VideoCapture.

Прошу объяснить почему так происходит, и какие есть возможности подключиться к этой трансляции без посещения сайта через браузер? Хочу периодически получать фотографии с этой камеры, чтобы наблюдать за волнами, но каждый раз приходится заходить на сайт через браузер, чтобы это получилось.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: по этому url-у можно только скачать файл playlist.m3u8

Comment: Возможно у сайта стоит защита. Передайте в headers user-agent. Когда я парсил сайт Амазона он тоже думал что я робот и не принимал запрос. Все решило добавление user agent. Можете воспользоваться библиотекой fake-useragent для генерации агента, далее создайте словарь header ={‘User-agent’: <ваш user agent>} и добавьте его в аргументы к функции requests